# How to display only the status message to anonymous users in page.tpl.php

Tags: status-messages

I want to display the status messages to all of the users but the error and warnings to the administrator.I am using this code

```
<?php if($is_admin): ?>
      <?php print $messages; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I have no idea how to distinguish the message type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14832/print-messages-in-node-tpl-php-file) seems like a similar question to yours regarding printing messages. Additionally, [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7) indicates that the message type is stored within the message object. You should just be able to iterate through a message object to get it. Something like

```
foreach (drupal_get_messages($messagesVariable) as $type => $messages) { 
    if (($status_heading[$type] != 'error') || ($status_heading[$type] != 'warning')) {
        *perform your given action here*
    }
}
```

Comment: it report the error *Notice: Undefined variable: messagesVariable in ...*

Comment: You need to define what messagesVariable is.

Comment: it should be the `$messages` variable which is provided by drupal, I replaced it with that but didn't work

Comment: Read the first link I referenced. You're going to need a preprocessor function. I think you'll need to modify the answer slightly, putting the `$variables['show_messages'] = FALSE` in `function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables)` and getting rid of the `$variables['messages'] = theme('status_messages');` line and the entire `preprocess_page` function.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't the option to not display error messages in /admin/config/development/logging solve this problem?

> "It is recommended that sites running on production environments do
>   not display any errors."

Admins can still see the notices/warnings in the watchdog (Reports > Recent log messages). Although you should really fix those notices, since by default those messages get logged to the watchdog, which means reducing the site's performance by writing in a database table.