# Is there an equivalent of drupal_set_message which will write to the block?

Tags: status-messages

I have some custom functionality running in `hook_block_view` such that when a user loads a page, different status messages may need to be displayed from multiple blocks in the page. At present I am outputting the messages via `drupal_set_message` so that they appear at the top of the page.

It would be more elegant if I could display the messages within the individual blocks. I could hack this and output the messages in divs with the relevant Drupal classes attached, but that seems like a bad idea. Is there some Drupal functionality I could call to achieve what I want? (a nice Drupal style message in each block, complete with coloured background and tick/cross icon as appropriate).

Thanks in advance,

MB

Comment: Have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14832/print-messages-in-node-tpl-php-file/57003#57003 and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/how-to-display-messages-from-a-block-separately-from-messages-in-page-tpl-php

Comment: Thank you very much for these suggestions. Unfortunately I don't think they will be useful for me, as my module needs to be theme-independent (I can't provide a YOURTHEME_preprocess_block or YOURTHEME_preprocess_page as I don't know which theme is going to be used.)